# Is there a way to use annotations with amsrefs?

Tags: bibliographies, amsrefs, annotations

I'm writing an annotated bibliography, and I can't get annotations to show up. I tried using the annotate style on natbib, but I would prefer the font size and citation style of amsrefs. I was wondering if there was a style in amsrefs that allows for annotations.

Please list the name of the style, the name of the field used for annotations, and any specific instructions for downloading and compiling.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to redefine the fields and add `annotations`, then redefine the output models to take care of the added field.

Comment: Could you explain or provide an example of what you mean? This is my first time using BibTeX, so I don't know much about it.

Comment: See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301179/ where just one bib entry type is changed. You can do similarly, by providing how an annotation should be printed (check the documentation for how to add a field type), but do so for every bib entry.